# HTML pages getting 'cut off' CGI/Perl

Tags: apache-2.2, perl, cgi

I noticed a problem with web pages getting 'cut off' with a Perl/CGI based proprietary application I administer on a server running Apache 2.2.  This lead me to investigate the problem further by writing a little Perl script myself I was able to recreate the same problem.  There is no particular place that the output gets cut off. I have considered the possibility of time outs but I cannot find any time out related errors in the web server logs.  The limits set for CGI appear to be fine too.

What measures can I take to identify the cause (and fix) this problem?

Comment: Which version of Perl?

Comment: The version of Perl is 5.8.8

Comment: Which OS do use use at server?

Comment: The OS is Debian Etch.

Answer (score 2):

Anyway, in case anyone is interested I found a solution to my problem.  The application wasn't providing a content-length.   When I wrote a script to buffer the output and append a content-length before displaying it to the browser the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you post the "little Perl script" here?  Are you writing to the screen with "print"?  Those shouldn't be buffered or anything.

Comment: I just mentioned that I could reproduce the problem by writing code but that's not the problem itself - as I mentioned I discovered the problem with this application hosted on the server so I believe there may be a problem with the environment that I need to figure out.